# Python syntax error while using lambda and data frame

Tags: python-3.x

I cant see what is the syntax error here! if can anybody help. thank you

```
for j in range(df.shape[0]):
     distances.append(lambda df['images'][j], image : math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(df['images'][j], image)])))
```

Comment: You're supposed to put parameter for `lambda` not `df['images'][j]`.

Comment: A missing `:` after the lambda? If not that, please post the full traceback

Comment: `lambda df['images'][j]` does not make sense.  That needs to be a variable name; same rules as if you were defining a function.  e.g. `def foo(df['images'][j]):` is also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

No need for lambda here and it is work now after i deleted lambda and both datafram and the variable! thank you

```
for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        distances.append(math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(df['images'][j], image)])))
```